# OkHttp upload PDF and PNG with Form Data

Tags: android, multipartform-data, okhttp, stetho

I have an app which will upload a PDF and PNG image file to the server, along with some other data. I'm using Stetho as inspector but everytime I try to open the log, it hangs and then crashes, so I have no idea if what I'm sending to the server is right.

Here are the required data (Method: POST, Content-Type: multipart/form-data):

- Content-Disposition: form-data
  name="SrcFile"
  Content-Type: application/pdf (The PDF File to upload)
- Content-Disposition: form-data; 
  name="SignFile"
  Content-Type: image/png (The PNG File to upload)
- Mode (String value)
- Req (String value)
- Token (String value)

This is my first to do this but based from my research, here is my code to upload said data:

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
   @Override
   public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
   }

   @Override
   public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
   }

   @Override
   public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          return null;
   }
 }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
       @Override
       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
              return true;
       }
});
client.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());

File pngFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "signature_" + pdfFile.getFileName() + ".png");
File pdf = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + pdfFile.getFileName());

String mode = "SampleMode"

Headers headers = new Headers.Builder()
        .add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .build();

MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder()
       .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
       .addFormDataPart("Req", "SampleRequest")
       .addFormDataPart("Token", "MyAPIToken")
       .addFormDataPart("Mode", mode)
       .addFormDataPart("SrcFile", pdf.getAbsolutePath(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), pdf))
       .addFormDataPart("SignFile", pngFile.getAbsolutePath(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), pngFile));

RequestBody requestBody = multipartBuilder
             .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url("MyURLHere")
             .headers(headers)
             .post(requestBody)
             .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I just would like to know if I'm doing the upload correctly, or maybe I set some parameters wrong. Again, I can't seem to use Stetho coz it hangs whenever I try to open it. Thanks!

**Edited** 
Turns out I just switched SrcFile and SignFile! XD
The upload works, now on to downloading the response.

Answer (score 0):

I Rather suggest you to use this [jar](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

**Use of this library**

```
SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
RequestParams param = new RequestParams();

param.put("email", email);
param.put("title", title);

try {
    if (!path.equals("") || path != null) {
        param.put("logo", new File(path));
    } else {
        path = " ";
        param.put("logo", new File(path));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String link = "your link";

client.post(link, param, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, String arg2) {
        success1 = "true";
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, String arg2,
            Throwable arg3) {
        success1 = "false";
    }
});
```